# ng bootstrap Accordion to cant add arrow down icon

Tags: css, angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap

Any one know how to to add [ng bootstrap Accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) for `icon-arrow-down`

I added this `<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>` but not work

This is my code

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
  <ngb-panel title="Task Tyeps (5)">  <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
   text.....
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

I try to add like this

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue

```
<ngb-accordion class="range-accordion">
    <ngb-panel>
        <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class="d-flex" style="font-weight: bold; color: #1c2128;">Checklist items</div>
                <div class="d-flex"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            text
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Add some custom styles for our requirements.

```
.range-accordion .btn-link {
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration-line: none;
}
```

Comment: :sir can you tell me how to default + icon in accodian?

Comment: @Kapilsoni m you should change the icon like as `<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>`

Comment: :actually sir in my case i have to show and hide default + icon via conditionally can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @Kapilsoni can you provide you conflict using  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: :i have already asked check it--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67085969/hide-default-or-icon-from-ngb-accordion-also-stop-expanding-collapse-in

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full code but I guess you didn't import Font Awesome. "icon-arrow-down" needs Font Awesome 3.2.1 library, try to add following in the `<head>` section of your page

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer  and , I already added  `font-awesome.css ` for my project